# Is getting the table size in JPA an expensive operation?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I implement server-side pagination for table viewing in my web application.  This means the user has buttons to activate first-page, last-page, next-page, and prior-page.   Each click results in a server request where only the records to be shown are returned.

To implement that "last page" function and a scroll bar I need the client to have the size of the table.   I can get this on the server-side with the following method:

```
public long getCount(Class entityClass) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root root = query.from(entityClass);
    Expression<Long> count = builder.count(root);
    query.select(count);
    TypedQuery<Long> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
    return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

This table could be very active with millions of records.  Does running this function cause a lot of CPU cycles in the SQL server to be utilized?

The concern is how well this application will scale.

Comment: We are currently dealing with this problem ourselves, and one comment I wish to make is that you might only need to do the count query once, but not on subsequent pages.  If so, then the cost of the `COUNT` query may not be the biggest factor in performance of your paginated search.

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on the database, all JPA implementations I know will translate count to `select count(*) from Table`. We have a Postgresql with single table with 130GB data, and most rows are only a few kilobytes. Doing `select (*) from table` takes minutes; a developer once did a simple undeindexed select query, and a full table scan takes about 45 minutes.

When doing pagination, you often have a filter, and it is important to apply the same fileter to both the data-query and the count-query (one of the main reasons for using CriteriaBuilder is to share the filtering part of the query). Today I would recommend using `Spring-data`, since it makes pagination almost effortlessly.

If you have a lots of data, you can do like google, which say there are 1.340.000.000 results for 'zip', but only allows you to jump 10 pages ahead, and if you run it to the end you will see that they only actually load 1000 pages. In other words they cache an estimate size, but require you to narrow the search to give you more precise results.